# Antivirus blocking the Qt App and "unknown developer" message

Tags: windows, macos

Some users of my **Qt Application** are reporting some issues about antivirus (**Windows**) and "unknown developer" (**OS X**).

1. In some cases, on **Windows**, the antivirus is blocking the application or showing a message that the application can be dangerous. What can I do to my **Qt Application** be "trustworthy" to the antivirus?
2. On **OS X**, when the user tries to run the application, the system shows a message about "**unknown developer**". What can I do to not show this message?

Unfortunately, I can not give more details about the problems because I could not replicate the problems on my machine. I am just asking based on the problems reported by the users.

Comment: There's really nothing about this that's specific to Qt.

Comment: You're right. I deleted the Qt tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS - you need to sign the app using a developer certificate.
You need a developer account for signing apps.
Users will still see a message after signing the app if it is not distributed via the AppStore, but unlike the 'unknown developer' message that only has a 'close' button, the user will have an option to open the app once it's signed.
I can only assume the same applies to windows (less restrictive if I remember correctly) - you probably need to sign the app using a certificate obtained from Microsoft.
You will not see this message when running on your own machine, unless you're using an archived and exported version of your app.
In order to fully test an app on your own machine - create a non administrative user (useful for testing how the app works for non admin users, regardless of signing issues) on your local machine and test the app using the newly created account.
Do not compile or debug the app using the new account, use that account just for testing.